Is there a strategy for a single-shot identification of a Pauli gate?
I am given a single qubit gate  $\in$ {I,X,Y,Z}. I can prepare any state, send it, and measure the result - but once. Is there a strategy to identify the gate?

Prepare a Bell pair $|00\rangle + |11\rangle$. Apply the gate to one of its qubits (either one; doesn't matter). Do a Bell basis measurement. The four possible measurement results are the four possible Paulis. This works for the same reason that superdense coding works.
It's important that this uses a two qubit state. With a single qubit state it's impossible to do what you want because of Holevo's bound. If you could get four distinguishable states out of the four Paulis, that would mean you managed to encode two bits into one qubit, violating the bound.

Thank you! Holevo's bound argument is very much in place.

Then, I guess, two shots (two single qubit states) would be enough. Is this correct? If yes - what are they?

Deterministically, no you cannot. Specifically, not with a strategy that looks like: prepare some single-qubit input $\rho$, apply the gate $U$ to it, and then measure with some POVM. Given any input $|\psi\rangle$, the question boils down to finding a discrimination strategy that can discriminate between $|\psi\rangle$, $X|\psi\rangle$, $Y|\psi\rangle$, and $Z|\psi\rangle$. Even if you have freedom to chose the initial state $|\psi\rangle$ the gates act upon, and full freedom to choose the measurement strategy, these four states are never going to be mutually orthogonal. Therefore there is no way to discriminate them deterministically.
If you're restricting even more to just doing a computational basis measurement after the gate, then it's even simpler to see, because you can never distinguish between $|\psi\rangle$ and $Z|\psi\rangle$, even with infinite statistics.
As mentioned by the other answer, you can do it if you use entanglement and apply the gate to only part of the state though.

Thank you for the answer. Would two shots suffice? If yes - what is the strategy?

And I cannot use POVM measurements, just the standard projective one (in the z-basis)

@trurl I feel like I need to ask what you actually mean by "two shots" here. Because as I mentioned in the answer, if you're only doing computational basis measurements, and the input is a single qubit, then you can't distinguish between $|\psi\rangle$ and $Z|\psi\rangle$ even with infinite statistics

I cannot distinguish between I and Z gate? Is this the statement?  I would simply pass the state $\vert 0 \rangle$. One shot would definitely be enough to identify the gate.

@trurl no, because $I|0\rangle= Z|0\rangle$

You are indeed right.  What if I am allowed to change the measurement basis? To be specific, I can rotate the state $U \vert \psi \rangle$ with any Pauli operator (that I choose) before measuring the state. Can I  now identify $U$ -- knowing that $U \in \lbrace I, X, Y, Z\rbrace$ -- with a finite number of a single-shot (consecutive) measurements?
